# Transparent Passwordbox in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Does anyone help me in creating a transparent password box in windows phone 8.1
Does blend helps for this.

Comment: What do you mean 'transparent'?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to do something like this (PasswordBox without background and border):

[image: PasswordBox without background and border]

If you want to create this you need to edit style of PasswordBox. Blend is best tool for that - when you start editing current template of control, you should change properties of BorderElement:

[image: PasswordBox Template (Blend)]

This is sample code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TransparentPasswordBoxStyle" TargetType="PasswordBox">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlMarginThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="PasswordBox">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="RevealButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked" Storyboard.TargetName="RevealButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="RevealButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked" Storyboard.TargetName="RevealButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" Margin="{ThemeResource RichEditBoxTextThemeMargin}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{ThemeResource RichEditBoxTextThemeMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="RevealButton" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundHeaderThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{ThemeResource PasswordBoxCheckBoxThemeMargin}" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <PasswordBox Style="{StaticResource TransparentPasswordBoxStyle}" Foreground="White" />
</Grid>
```